# how can i make this program show a result for a negative number?

Tags: python

One of my school assignments is to create a program where you can input a minimum number of passengers, a max number of passengers, and the price of a ticket. As the groups of passengers increase by 10, the price of the ticket lowers by 50 cents. At the end it is supposed to show the maximum profit you can make with the numbers input by the user, and the number of passengers and ticket price associated with the max profit. This all works, but when you input numbers that result in a negative profit, i get a run time error. What am i doing wrong? I have tried making an if statement if the profit goes below 0, but that doesn't seem to work. here is my work for you all to see. A lead in the right direction or constructive criticism would be a great help.

```
    #first variables
passengers = 1
maxcapacity = 500
maxprofit = 0
ticketprice = 0
fixedcost = 2500

#inputs and outputs
again = 'y'

while (again == 'y'):
    minpassengers = abs(int(input("Enter minimum number of passengers: ")))
    maxpassengers = abs(int(input("Enter maximum number of passengers: ")))
    ticketprice = abs(float(input("Enter the ticket price: ")))

    if (minpassengers < passengers):
        minpassengers = passengers
        print ("You need at least 1 passenger. Setting minimum passengers to 1.")

    if (maxpassengers > maxcapacity):
        maxpassengers = maxcapacity
        print ("You have exceeded the max capacity. Setting max passengers to 500.")

    print ("Passenger Run from", minpassengers, "to", maxpassengers, "with an initital ticket price of $",format (ticketprice, "7,.2f"), "with a fixed cost of $2500.00\n"
           "Discount per ticket of $0.50 for each group of 10 above the starting count of", minpassengers, "passengers")

    for n in range (minpassengers, maxpassengers + 10, 10):
        ticketcost = ticketprice - (((n - minpassengers)/10) * .5)
        gross = n * ticketcost
        profit = (n * ticketcost) - fixedcost 

        print ("Number of \nPassengers", "\t Ticket Price \t Gross \t\t Fixed Cost \t Profit")
        print ("  ", n, "\t\t$", format (ticketcost, "7,.2f"), "\t$", format (gross, "5,.2f"), "\t$", format(fixedcost, "5,.2f"), "\t$", format (profit, "5,.2f"))

        if (profit > maxprofit):
            maxprofit = profit
            maxpass = n
            best_ticket = ticketcost


    print ("Your max profit is $", format (maxprofit, "5,.2f"))
    print ("Your max profit ticket price is $", format (best_ticket,"5,.2f"))
    print ("Your max profit number of passengers is", maxpass)
    again = input ("Run this again? (Y or N): ")
    again = again.lower()
    print ("\n")
```

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" You don't tell us the runtime error, and you don't tell us where it occurs.

Comment: if i input numbers that will result in nothing but a negative profit it show "Your max profit is $0.00" and then crashes with this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rooftopz/Documents/Python Assignments/cruise ship test.py", line 42, in <module>
    print ("Your max profit ticket price is $", format (best_ticket,"5,.2f"))
NameError: name 'best_ticket' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is probably because the variable you are outputting is defined in a spot that doesn't get executed.

```
    if (profit > maxprofit):
        maxprofit = profit
        maxpass = n
        best_ticket = ticketcost
```

So, whenever the if condition is False, best_ticket never gets assigned.

Try adding best_ticket = 0 at the top of your code.

```
ticketprice = abs(float(input("Enter the ticket price: ")))
best_ticket = -1 #nonsense value that warns you whats happening.
```

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because the condition `profit > maxprofit` never evaluates to True in the situation where your profit is negative, because `maxprofit` is set to 0 up at the top. This in turn means that `best_ticket` never gets assigned a value in this case, and so Python can't print it out later.

You could avoid this problem either by setting a default value for `best_ticket` earlier in the program:

```
best_ticket = 0
```

or by adding a condition that you only print out a best ticket price when `best_ticket` is set:

```
# Earlier in the program.
best_ticket = None

if best_ticket is not None:
    print("Your max profit ticket price is $", format(best_ticket,"5,.2f"))
```

Also, FYI, the same problem will occur for the `maxpass` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is telling you the problem

`NameError: name 'best_ticket' is not defined`

You define best_ticket in this block

```
    if (profit > maxprofit):
        maxprofit = profit
        maxpass = n
        best_ticket = ticketcost
```

Regardless of the truth of that statement, you reference best_ticket below

```
print ("Your max profit ticket price is $", format (best_ticket,"5,.2f"))
```